# Retrolink SNES USB controller not working

Tags: controllers, emulation, snes

The Retrolink SNES USB Controller says that it works without drivers or anything, but then doesn't seem to work with any of my SNES emulators.  [Here's a link to it](http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/f08d/?srp=2#tabs).

i tried it with snes9x and another one and neither seemed to work.  When I plug it in, my computer doesn't recognize the device and troubleshooting the device obviously does nothing.

Comment: Try uninstalling it from the device manager and plugging it out and back in.

Comment: it didn't seem to work

Comment: Is it tested working? It could just be broken.

Comment: hmm that's a possibility i guess.  is there any way i could figure that out

Comment: Plug it into different computers?

Comment: tried that too, didn't work in my laptop or desktop. i might just complain to where i got it from

Comment: wonder why the -1...

Comment: haterz gonna hate

Comment: I bought two of these and windows8 configures the controllers driver wrong. I spent hours searching the internet and trying different things with no luck. I think it might work if i could figure out how to use a compatibility mode bc people with older OS's say that their's work.

Comment: mine was on windows 7.  the second one worked for like 10 seconds at one point, so there's always hope in this world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess the answer is that it was broken or is simply magical.  But really it was just broken i guess.

Maybe I'll take it apart to see if anything specific was broken.

Answer (score -3):

This might help a lot.

What you need: Oracle Virtual Box and a Windows XP disk.

Plug in SNES controller or controller that is currently not compatible with Windows 7 or 8. Install Oracle Virtual Box and XP inside it (if you don't know how to do this, there are instructions on youtube:

). Once done Windows 7 or 8 will somehow get the driver from XP and now you will be able to use a controller that was once incompatible.

Comment: You might have to run XP in Virtual Box while you use the SNES controller.